# Can I link two servers directly through two 40GbE cards, like it was done with crossover cables?

Tags: networking

I have server A and server B (a file backup unit), both with 40GbE cards. My need is to speed up file backup from A to B. Can I link those cards directly with a QSFP cable, like it was done with crossover cables back in the day?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

These cables are already crossover. TX on A directly connects to RX on B, and vice versa.

Also, all recent cards have auto-MDIX so they can detect what kind of cable is used.

Comment: So basically plug them together, use a local 169.* IP, and that's it?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: I would use real local IPs like something from `10.0.0.0/8`, `192.168.0.0/16` or `172.16.0.0/12`. Using autoconfiguration space `169.*` might cause issues.